# click event for LWUIT label

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am new to LWUIT platform. I am developing an application and I 
want to add click events to Label and a container.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: accept the answers which you think are good by selecting the tick mark besides the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `Label`is not for clickable events. Use a `Button` with an aspect of a `Label`. It will be more easy for you. `Containers`could have click events but It will be harder.

Comment: Here you have the explanation of theming http://today.java.net/article/2010/04/19/using-styles-themes-and-painters-lwuit

Comment: In this blog you can find some tutorials which will help you http://lwuit.blogspot.com.es/

Comment: How can you make a container clickable?

Comment: Yes, make a question and I will answer it